# How to migrate mongoid model to model with same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

So I have a User model using Mongoid::Documents and I'm adding some field and removing one.

1. How do I move this model to the new model without downtime?
2. Any traps I'm bound to find?

(learning rails)